# Using componentsSeparatedByString with more than one separator string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I have a string that I need to separate into an array of words. I was using     `NSArray *words = [cleanText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];` which worked fine, until I ran into the end of a paragraph resulting in the component "end.\n\nStart".

Is there a way to separate the string into components using " " as well as "\n\n" character? Or is there more correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on the `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet`. You will get empty “words” when `cleanText` has more than one split character in a row, and you probably want to filter those out.

```
NSArray *words = [@"" componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
words = [words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id object, NSDictionary *_) {
        return [object length] > 0;
    }]];
```

Comment: I get an incompatible block pointer types sending 'int(^)(_strong id, NSDictionary *_strong)

Comment: This really saved my bacon; thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are describing splitting a string using a regular expression such as `"\s"`. If you look at e.g. https://github.com/bendytree/Objective-C-RegEx-Categories/blob/master/RegExCategories.m you can obtain code for splitting on a regular expression match.

Alternatively you can split on a character set by calling [componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:) and use [whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet).